# Convert from decimal to Binary function

Tags: python

I tried creating a function to convert to binary the long way but i keep getting a very basic error that i can't seem to figure out. Would appreciate an extra pair of eyes.

```
def convert_to_binary(n):

    if (-1.0 < n < 256.0):
        number_list = []
        while (n != 0):
            rem = n % 2
            number_list.append(rem)
            n = n // 2

        new_list = number_list[::-1]
        print("".join(str(x) for x in new_list))

    else:
       print("Invalid input")
```

the error i keep getting is:

`File "", line 13
    else :
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I'd really appreciate any feedback. Thanks

Comment: It worked fine without the else statement

Comment: are you sure you are not mixing spaces and tabs?

Comment: You have 7 spaces before `print("Invalid input")` but you are using blocks of 4 spaces for everything else.

Comment: Your error message has a space between the else and the colon. Are you sure your code here is EXACTLY how it is in your file?

Comment: i thought about that and deleted and rewrote it but still the same. Maybe i'm missing something

Comment: i tried all your suggestions but still not working. Can't believe i'm having trouble with an if-else statement

Comment: Just tried your code and works fine for me!

Comment: Works for me too. Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Man, http://pastebin.com/bG8BSgW2 - run this in bash. The code you posted works. You had some additional or missing whitespace characters in your actual code (which is not posted here). Assuming python 3.

Comment: @Farhan.K was using an online ide guess thats why, but it works now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def convert_to_binary(n):
   if (-1.0 < n < 256.0):
      print '{0:b}'.format(n)
   else:
      print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: This doesn't really help... OP still has a problem with _his_ code

Comment: @Farhan.K SyntaxError already been fixed in comments. just let OP know easy way to do the work

Comment: @Farhan.K thanks it works now. Just started all over and it turned out fine